# Connect to a remote jupyter lab instance via proxy

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to connect to a remote `jupyter notebook`.

Server-side actions:

1. I simply use `jupyter notebook` command that produces the following output:

   http://localhost:8888/?token=c7a760ee5387de7d6a1cb797a0685a116621f8b3b5a1a5ba
2. I know that there's password authentication procedure as well. I set up the `jupyter_notebook_config.py` file. I changed the `c.NotebookApp.password` and `c.NotebookApp.open_browser` variables.

Client-side actions:

1. Since I'm using Putty I can copy/paste the HTTP address (with token) to a local browser. I get the following page:

[image]

Even though I'm using the token from the link (step 1) and password (step 2) I get the *Invalid Credentials* error.

There's a proxy server between the local machine and the server but I don't know how to account for that fact.

### Update 11.10.2019

I decided to tweak some parameters in `.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` file. By sacrificing security I did away with token authentication by setting `c.NotebookApp.token=''`. I still get the `Invalid credentials` message.

Comment: What output you get after pasting just the token part from the localhost:... link to tet box where it asks for password or token:. I think that proxy is not a issue because if proxy was not set up correctly, then you should not have seen the page above also.

Comment: I get `Invalid credentials` message. To be more precise: upon inspecting the webpage that is rendered on localhost:8888 there's POST method with 401 code (Unauthorized) when I enter the token or password.

Comment: have you set up the tunnel correctly in putty, since you are accessing jupyter from remote machine ?

Comment: Since I can connect to the remote machine via Putty i.e. I have a terminal from the remote on my local machine, the tunneling is done correctly, I suppose.

Comment: can you keep the variable `c.NotebookApp.password` as it was earlier (default) and try again.

Comment: I keep the `c.NotebookApp.password` commented out. I still get the `Invalid credentials` message.

Comment: this is weird. I use this way only and everyday. Actually, when you just paste that link in the browser, it should not even ask for password or token. Maybe you can try with fresh run, stop everything and try again.

Comment: I've tried this numerous times, to be honest.

Comment: One quick suggestion. It'd be more convenient to use cygwin (linux command line for Windows) rather than Putty (ssh/reverse ssh, etc.), and you can check the steps here https://medium.com/@alexjsanchez/python-3-notebooks-on-aws-ec2-in-15-mostly-easy-steps-2ec5e662c6c6

Comment: Thank you for your input. Considering point 12 (especially the `ssh -NfL 9999:localhost:8888 ec2` command), tunneling is done in Putty: I map the remote port 8888 to local 8888. As I mentioned in the comment the POST method that sends token/password to the server returns 401 (Authentication error).

Comment: @balkon16 can you try with `jupyter notebook --port=<port number>` on the remote server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jupyter_notebook_config.py` which resides in `.jupyter` directory (in the home directory of the user) is created with `jupyter notebook --generate-config`. All of the options are commented out. You need to find `c.NotebookApp.ip` variable that must not be commented out and set its value to the IP of the server the Jupyter is running on. If you want to connect to that instance of Jupyter from another machine you need to find `localhost:port` webpage with a browser of your choosing. My answer assumes that you've forwarded the port you are using.